# This code works running from Aptana but fails in python HTMLParser

Tags: python, aptana

So that's the point, in Aptana 3 wiyh pyDev i get no exceptions, everything seems to be fine.

But when i try to run directly in python, the bucle stops in some point, i guess it can be a match with some special character like ó or something like that.

```
class Spider(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, url):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        string=[]
        string2=[]
        self.feed(urlopen(url).read()

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'a' and attrs:
            title= attrs[1][1]
            link= attrs[0][1]
            string.append(title)
            string2.append(link)
```

Im kinda newbie in python, so i couldn'te get better exception information than this:

```
line 33, in __init__ self.feed(urlopen(url).read()) File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 108, 
in feed self.goahead(0)  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 148, 
in goahead k = self.parse_starttag(i)  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 252, 
in parse_starttag attrvalue = self.unescape(attrvalue)'])
```

Output from raise:

```
  File "parse.py", line 65, in <module>
    Spider("http://...")
  File "parse.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.feed(urlopen(url).read())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 108, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 148, in goahead
    k = self.parse_starttag(i)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 252, in parse_starttag
    attrvalue = self.unescape(attrvalue)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/HTMLParser.py", line 390, in unescape
    return re.sub(r"&(#?[xX]?(?:[0-9a-fA-F]+|\w{1,8}));", replaceEntities, s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, 0).sub(repl, string, count)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Now i can skip the errors by changing this:

```
self.feed(unicode(urlopen(url).read(),errors='replace'))
```

But still a ugly solution, i need accents in the text.
I tryed

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
```

but nothing changed.

Comment: Are you using the same version of python on Aptana/Pydev? (`python2.6`)

Comment: Are you sure its running the same version of python>?

Comment: I fixed your formatting for you.  Also, the code you posted isn't well-formed, at `self.feed(urlopen(url).read()` ... unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Use `raise` (without arguments) to rethrow the current exception to get a stack trace on the console. We need the actual exception message.

Comment: @Mario Im using python2.7 in pydev but configured interpreter in 2.6, anyway, the code also fail running in 2.7, checked

Comment: @Aaron can you explain how to use raise? try: Spider(url) except: raise?

Comment: @Jim the code fails if i remove the last parentheses of <code>self.feed(urlopen(url).read())</code>

Comment: The stack trace in your question is a list of stack frames, not a formatted stack trace from the console. We're missing some important information. `try: Spider(url) except: raise` will only work if `Spider(url)` doesn't contain some `try-except` which swallows the exception.

Comment: @Aaron edited with raise info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Max's solution didn't work.

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'

I finally got it to work by adding:

```
z=urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
self.feed(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('latin-1')
```

Some related reading: [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: Most systems today use `utf-8` as default encoding.